# DataGridView Change cell to ComboBox, Edit, then return cell to TextBox with selected value

Tags: vb.net

I've found another topic on this site, similar to my question,  "Change Cell to Combobox on focus and TextBox after loosing focus" but no answer has been given to date.

I have a DataGridView with a "Start Odometer" column, an "End Odometer" column and a "Units" column. They are populated through Bindings from a datatable.

I want to be able to change the units of selected records and convert the Odometer column values to the selected "Unit". (either miles to kilometers or visa versa).

I've figured out how to change and load the "Units" cell to a ComboBox cell. Here is the code.

```
        Dim gridComboBox As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
        With DataGridView1
            If .Rows.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
            Dim i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index

            Dim celval = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value

            gridComboBox.Items.Add(celval) 'Populate the Combobox
            gridComboBox.Items.Add("km") 'Populate the Combobox
            gridComboBox.Items.Add("mi") 'Populate the Combobox
            .Item(GridEnum.State, i) = gridComboBox
        End With
```

Here is where I run into problems.

I need to change this cell back to TextBox. I've basically used the same code as above substituting DataGridViewTextBoxCell.

```
        Dim gridTextBox As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
        With DataGridView1
            If .Rows.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
            Dim i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index

            Dim celval = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value

            gridTextBox.value = celVal

            .Item(GridEnum.State, i) = gridTextBox 
        End With
```

This last piece of code works if I call it as a separate procedure but it doesn't work if I run it from inside the ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged procedure. (EditingControlShowing is enabled).

This makes sense as the ComboBox is still active.

The question... How can I revert cell ComboBox back to cell TextBox once the ComboBox Item index has changed? I need this event to trigger my Odometer values conversion code as well.

Comment: What you're doing is just plain wrong.  Don't change the type of the cell at all.  Just use a combo box cell all the time.  If you don't want the cell to look like a `ComboBox` control when that cell doesn't have focus then simply set the `DisplayStyle` of the column to `Nothing`. Each cell will then display no drop-down button or `ComboBox` chrome when not focused, making it look exactly like a text box cell.

Comment: You are the man! (or woman. not sure by handle;-) ) Works like a charm. Now I've got to find how to mark as answered.

Comment: Man it is! :) If someone actually posts an answer, you can accept that as a correct answer to your question.  I posted my response as a comment rather than an answer because it indicated an alternative option that rendered the question moot, rather than providing an answer to the question as asked.  You can always post an answer yourself and accept that.